# while configuring TFS 2010 am getting this error

Tags: tfs

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 Express edition and intalled the analysis services n database"Adventure works" too. while configuring TFS 2010 am getting this error. how to solve it?

Error   [ Reporting ] TF255344: Either a connection could not be made to the server that is running SQL Server Analysis Services, or the service is not running. For more information, review the following exception message: Error encountered when creating connection to Analysis Services. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator..

Error   [ Reporting ] TF255353: You cannot perform the initial setup and configuration because you do not have sufficient permissions on the server that is running SQL Server Reporting Services. Verify that your role membership on the report server allows you to manage content and system settings.

Error   [ Reporting ] TF255151: Service is not installed: SQL Server Analysis Services

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the TFS 2010 Power Tools from here: [TFS 2010 power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f), then click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools, point to Microsoft Visual Studio Best Practices Analyzer, and then click TfsBpa.exe. It does a great job of diagnosing these kind of issues.